# How to compare two values with SQL in Google Big Query?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, countif, unnest

I am trying to get from the Google Big Query database all records which have the same value in different columns. Let's say, when sending some event from the phone I am setting variable `machine_name` to the firebase `user_properties`. And then I am sending the event `event_notification_send`. And when I am querying table - I want to fetch all data from DB with events with name `event_notification_send` which has parameter `machine_name` with some value X1 and that record must at the same time have a parameter in `user_properties`, in key `Last_notification` with the same value X1.

How can I do that SQL query?

Thanks.

Here is sample of my code:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM 
`myProject.analytics_159820162.events_*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180725' AND '20180727' 
AND event_name in ("event_notification_received", "event_notification_dissmissed")
AND platform = "ANDROID"
AND
(SELECT COUNTIF((key = "machine_name")) 
              FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
) > 0  -- to see if specified event has such key
AND
(SELECT COUNTIF((key = "Last_notification")) 
              FROM UNNEST(user_properties) 
) > 0  -- to see if specified event has such key
ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if row/event has parameters "machine_name" and "Last_notification" with same value you can use below statement

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT key) cnt
FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
WHERE key IN ("machine_name", "Last_notification")
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Assuming that the rest of your query in question is correct - below adds your criteria to it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `myProject.analytics_159820162.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180725' AND '20180727' 
AND event_name IN ("event_notification_received", "event_notification_dissmissed")
AND platform = "ANDROID"
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT key) cnt
    FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE key IN ("machine_name", "Last_notification")
    GROUP BY value
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) = 2  
ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC
```

Note: using below is just to be on safe side in case if event has multiple parameters wit the same keys but different values

```
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```